# Can demons use abjuration?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-2e, demon-the-descent

As normally demons have a core and not a soul I would say no BUT then again it could be that a demon could be found out by just a simple test in regards to if he is able to abjurate a ghost.

So my question is: Can demons use abjuration in any way?

Comment: Kinda Related: http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/44486/are-demons-able-to-effectively-deal-with-angels-in-the-twilight

Comment: looks like an endless look between the two questions :) that one is referencing this one for the "no only mortals"

Comment: Yeah, that was intentional. Noticed this one. It's answer corrects a mistake in that one. And also that one is of interest to anyone who comes to this one wanting a solution to dealing with twilight beings as demon. Links form a directed hypergraph (if I have my terms right)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### No

> Faith and will are powerful things. A mortal may use an abjuration or
>   prayer against spirits much as she would against a ghost. Abjurations
>   are prayers or rites meant to banish a spirit from the presence of the
>   faithful, disrupting its manifestation and keeping it at bay for a
>   short time. Abjuration calls for a contested Resolve + Composure roll
>   versus the spirit's Power + Resistance.

Demons are not mortals, so they can't use mortals powers.  Also please note that spirit abjuration is not what people do daily between breakfast and morning paper - most mortals would fail it as well by simply running away in fear.

Comment: Would it be possible to add a citation for your quote? I'd add it myself, but I have not been able to find this exact passage.

Answer (score 0):

Yes as a spoof.

Roll Cover to spoof, then the successes in the spoof or Resolve + Composure, whichever is the lowest.

Else this distinction could be used to detect Demons.

Comment: Incorrect: Spoofing from page 112 of DtD core; "...Whenever a demon is subjected to an effect that might reveal
her to be a supernatural being, she may attempt to “spoof” the
effect, fooling it into thinking she’s an ordinary human...".
The inability to perform Aburation is not an effect being done to the Demon. Spoofing is for tricking the activated, or passive abilities (spells, numina etc) of others. Not for being able to do everything your cover should be able to do (For that, see Legend. But I don't think you can Legend up Abjuration, it is not a skill or a merit)