# Angel forms - Should I use Demonic forms as a template?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-2e, demon-the-descent

After reading through all the books that I can find (CoD, DtD, DSG, Iface, etc.), I cannot find any rules for Angelic forms.

Black Nathaniel in CoD states that he flies around and he has black wings.  However, I see no stats for it (maybe I missed it?).

What are thoughts on using the Demonic forms as a template?  Just spin it as an angelic theme (i.e. use feathery, smoke-like or mechanical wings as opposed to using bat-like wings).  Use the "claws and fangs" or "barbed tail" for a "razor wing attack"... that kind of thing.

Does anyone have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you can't find rules for creating Angelic Forms,
is because angels do not work that way.
They almost do, but not quiet.

Angels use the same mechanics as spirits, ghosts and other ephemeral entities.
(It is a bit awkward that they do, since they are rarely ephemeral (IMO) if they are  [demons can't generally deal with them then.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/44486/1362), but rewriting them is another question.)
For powers, they have Numina. (As well as manifestations and influences, but mostly numina)

They don't have a Cover form and a Angelic Form.
So no Angel form abilities.
What they do have is the Mortal Mask numina.
And when they stop using that you could say they enter "Angelic Form".
But they actually have the form abilities (i.e. numina) all the time.

Anyway, with all that aside, to answer your question.
**The book suggests that yes, embeds and demon form abilities can/should be used as the basis for homebrewing numina**.
(I don't have my books on me, or I'ld give a page ref).
In theory exploits should not be used as the basis of numina.

(Related: I made a [webapp](http://oxinabox.ucc.asn.au/rpg/eegen/) for generating angels using the rules from the GMC-RU a while ago)

Comment: WOW!!!  It looks great!  Take a look at the Demon Storyteller's Guide.  It has some new stuff like new Numina, Incepts and such.